# align slick slider items to left side

Tags: html

I am using slick slider . I have managed setting slide to show item 4 but when user upload only two slick item it align to right of container but i need to it align left side of container.

```
     $('#blog-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    // autoplaySpeed: 0,
    // speed: 5000,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    loop: true,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                   slidesToScroll: 2
                
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 800,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 2
                
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 2
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1
            }
        }

    ]
});

[related image][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of slides before initializing the slider and if slide number is greater than 4 you can enable **centermode** which will align your slide on left or center. Check fiddle here

```
var enableCenterMode = false;
if($('.single-slide').length > 4){
    enableCenterMode = true;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/er10y3p9/)

if you are adding slides dynamically you can also use **slickSetOption** and check the slide length and enable or disable centermode.